# AppleScript Key code Application isn't running (-600)

Tags: macos, applescript, keycode, keystroke

I am having a problem with running key code 123 (Left Arrow). Whenever I try to run it, it works fine for few times then I get System Events got an error: Application isn't running (-600), and it would highlight (Key Code 123) part. This problem started occurring only after the Big Sur update. I have checked "Allow these apps to control your computer" still not working. However, if I change this Applescript into the application it works fine without any problem. I also tried sending key strokes 123 but it just typing 123.

Here's my code

```
tell application "System Events"
    delay 4
    repeat 50 times
        delay 1
        key code 123
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: RE: "System Events got an error: Application isn't running (-600)" --  This has become a very common error with running **AppleScript** _code_ in **macOS Big Sur** and the only _workaround_ I found is to use the `launch` _command_ with a `delay` after` tell application "System Events"` before any other _code_ that **System Events** is supposed to process, and even then it is not 100%. **Apple** has obviously seriously hampered the use of **System Events** in **macOS Big Sur** and I suspect it will only get worse as **Apple** continues its _iOS-sification_  of **macOS**.

Comment: As to the `keystroke` _command_, that is normal and expected behavior when an _edit field_ has focus. When using **System Events** you need to first make sure that the target of it has focus and is frontmost by telling the target _application_ to `active`.

Comment: I have tried putting launch, run, activate in before delay 4 but the problem is still there. I am only using this code for a single game instead of grinding so i don't know much about apple script

Comment: I've got a computer on Catalina that is doing this same thing. All of the services I wrote to use spotlight aren't working because I cannot do `keystroke space using {command} down`. WTH?